# JFrog docker registry Public View

Tags: jfrog-container-registry

We are evaluating  Jfrog  container registry to host our docker images and host is public ally , so that users can view  them but pulling require authentication .

As i see JFROG only has list browsing[1]  to expose docker images publicly. that view basically a very primitive UI.

So my questions is , Is there any proper Docker registry user interface available  in Jfrog to expose them publicly ?

[1] https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JCR6X/Browsing+JFrog+Container+Registry

Comment: There's also package view, which is more Docker Image oriented in JCR. Have you tried that?
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JCR6X/Viewing+Packages

Answer (score 0):

JFrog Container Registry Package Viewer offers a package-centric UI that makes it easier to find and view the details of packages of a specific type.
The Package Viewer is available by selecting the Packages module in the left navigation bar.
The Package Viewer is initially displayed empty. To search for packages, select the type of package you are looking for from the drop list, and provide a search term. Note you can use the '?' and '*' wildcards in the same way they are used in JFrog Container Registry's Search module. The Package Viewer will display all packages that match your search term from all repositories that you have permissions to view.
For more details please refer to the below wiki page.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JCR6X/Viewing+Packages